# modifying a file using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with following format

```
    A  something_A something_A something_A
    B  something_B something_B something_B
    C  something_C something_C something_C
```

Whenever I get A in the first column, want to add a line with all the values same, with A replaced by let's say Z. Final file should be:

```
    A  something_A something_A something_A
    Z  something_A something_A something_A
    B  something_B something_B something_B
    C  something_C something_C something_C
```

How to do this in bash, using sed/awk ?

Comment: original fine should be overwritten with the output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through sed,

```
$ sed -i 's/^\( *\)A\( \+.*\)/&\n\1Z\2/' file
    A  something_A something_A something_A
    Z  something_A something_A something_A
    B  something_B something_B something_B
    C  something_C something_C something_C
```

`&` prints the entire match. `^\( *\)` would capture the leading spaces. Change spaces in the above regex to `[[:space:]]` or `[[:blank:]]`. Because space in the above regex won't match tabs. Add in-line edit `-i` parameter to save the changes made to that file.

Comment: You can make a small change.. if leading tabs, it's not working... still, +1.

Comment: simple, change space to `[[:blank:]]`

Comment: add inline edit i option `sed -i 's/^\( *\)A\( \+.*\)/&\n\1Z\2/' file`

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '$1~/A/{print;sub(/A/,"Z")}1' File
```

**Sample:**

```
AMD$ cat File
A  something_A something_A something_A
B  something_B something_B something_B
C  something_C something_C something_C
AMD$ awk '$1~/A/{print;sub(/A/,"Z")}1' File
A  something_A something_A something_A
Z  something_A something_A something_A
B  something_B something_B something_B
C  something_C something_C something_C
```

Check if the first field matches A (`$1~/A/`). If matching, print that line as it is, replace the first `A` in the same line with `Z`. This will get printed again. `1` used at end to print even the unmatched lines.

Comment: does it preserve the leading spaces?

Comment: A bit of rearranging and you don't need the print :) `awk '1;$1~/A/&&sub($1,"Z")'`